# Apache alias: making shortcuts

Tags: apache, alias, httpd.conf

I'm wanting to do something like the following:

(in browser address bar, with no forward slashes)

```
fa234
```

And have this point to http://localhost/FA234

In my httpd.conf I used

```
Redirect permanent /fa234 http://localhost/FA234
```

but this assumes /fa234 in the address bar is preceded by localhost.

Is there a way to configure httpd.conf so a simple word (without slashes) points to a web address?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

No because this is not a task for apache. 
If you enter fa234 your browser tries to look up the ip adress for this hostname. If it is only local and you don't want to use DNS you can modify your hosts file and enter fa234 localhost so that it will be redirected to localhost. But as said above this is not possible by configuring apache